# Programação com cliente e servidor: Como conseguir inúmeras trocas de dados por cliente e inúmeros clientes simultaneamente?

Tags: python, python-3.x, servidor, multithreading

O cliente:

```
from socket import *


serverHost = 'localhost'
serverPort = 50007

# Menssagem a ser mandada codificada em bytes
menssagem = [b'Ola mundo da internet!']

# Criamos o socket e o conectamos ao servidor
sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sockobj.connect((serverHost, serverPort))

# Mandamos a menssagem linha por linha
for linha in menssagem:
    sockobj.send(linha)

    # Depois de mandar uma linha esperamos uma resposta
    # do servidor
    data = sockobj.recv(1024)
    print('Cliente recebeu:', data)

# Fechamos a conexão
sockobj.close()
```

O servidor:

```
from socket import *
import time

# Cria o nome do host
meuHost = '' #maquina local = localhost = 127.0.0.1/0.0.0.0

# Utiliza este número de porta
minhaPort = 50007


sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) #AF_INET é IP; SOCK_STREAM = TCP

# Vincula o servidor ao número de porta
sockobj.bind((meuHost, minhaPort))

# O socket começa a esperar por clientes limitando a 
# 5 conexões por vez
sockobj.listen(5)


while True:
    # Aceita uma conexão quando encontrada e devolve a
    # um novo socket conexão e o endereço do cliente
    # conectado
    conexão, endereço = sockobj.accept()
    print('Server conectado por', endereço)

    while True: #só existe 1 troca de dados por cliente conectado!
        # Recebe data enviada pelo cliente
        data = conexão.recv(1024) #recebe 1024 bytes
        # time.sleep(3)

        # Se não receber nada paramos o loop
        if not data: break

        # O servidor manda de volta uma resposta
        conexão.send(b'Eco=>' + data)

    # Fecha a conexão criada depois de responder o
    # cliente
    conexão.close()
```

Problema: Só existe 1 troca de dados por cliente conectado! Após a primeira troca de dados, a conexão é encerrada!

Como modificar o servidor de forma a possibilitar inúmeras trocas de dados, até o cliente resolver encerrar a conexão?

Problema2: O servidor só lida com 1 cliente por vez: Como torná-lo capaz de lidar com vários clientes simultaneamente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problema 1: Não existe só "1 troca de dados por cliente conectado!"; existem várias, dependendo do tamanho da tua lista de mensagens a enviar/receber pelo cliente.

Problema 2: O servidor lida só com uma conecção pois programaste para ficar fincado/a processar uma só conecção, aí falta como disseste, threads, uma para cada cliente.

Parece-me a que só queres que o servidor reencaminhe a mesma mensagem para o cliente que a mandou, então esses programas (servidor e cliente) podem ser feitos assim (*python3 style*): (Explicações ao longo do código em comentário)

Servidor:

```
import socket, threading

def handle_client(client_conn):
    while True:
        data = client_conn.recv(1024) # a espera de receber alguma coisa
        if(not data):
            print(client_conn.getpeername(), 'disconectou-se')
            return
        client_conn.send(b'Eco=>' + data) # enviar msg para o mesmo cliente que mandou

with socket.socket() as s: # por default ja abre socket AF_INET e TCP (SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) # reutilizar porta logo após servidor terminal, evita a excepcao 'OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use'
    s.bind(('', 50007)) # localhost por default no primeiro elemento do tuple
    s.listen(5)
    while True: # aceitar todas as conexoes que possam vir
        conexao, endereco = s.accept() # a espera de conexao
        print('Server conectado por', endereco)
        threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conexao,)).start() # comecar thread para lidar com o cliente, uma para cada cliente
```

Cliente(s):

```
import socket, select, sys

with socket.socket() as s: # por default ja abre socket AF_INET e TCP (SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('', 50007))
    while True:
        io_list = [sys.stdin, s]
        ready_to_read,ready_to_write,in_error = select.select(io_list , [], [])   # visto que as funcoes input e recv sao 'bloqueadoras' da execucao do codigo seguinte temos de 'seguir' ambos os eventos desta maneira
        if s in ready_to_read: # caso haja dados a chegar
            data = s.recv(1024)
            if(not data): # ex: caso o servidor se desligue, ou conexao perdida
                break
            print(data.decode())  # decode/encode por default e utf-8
        else: # enviar msg
            msg = sys.stdin.readline() # capturar mensagem inserida no terminial, no command prompt
            s.send(msg.encode())  # decode/encode por default e utf-8
            sys.stdout.flush()
```

[DOCS](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select) de `select`

Se quiseres só fazer isso que estás a fazer, enviar/receber uma lista de mensagens podes simplificar o teu client para:

```
import socket

mgs = ['msg1', 'msg2', 'msg3']
with socket.socket() as s:
    s.connect(('', 50007))
    for msg in mgs:
        s.send(msg.encode())
        print(s.recv(1024).decode()) # decode/encode por default e utf-8
```

Maneira de usar/testar:
     - correr servidor: e.g `python3 server.py`
     - abrir 2 ou mais terminais com: e.g `python3 client.py` e enviar mensagens de cada um deles

Nota: Deves evitar o uso de caracteres especiais em nomes de objs/variáveis ("conexão", "endereço").

[Aqui](https://github.com/Miguel-Frazao/simple-chat) deixo um servidor/cliente de chat que fiz em tempos um pouco mais completo.

Comment: Tentei fazer sozinho uma versão com Threads. Editei a pergunta. O que você acha?

Comment: Desculpe! Não havia pensado nisso! Já voltei a pergunta ao estado anterior! Código do servidor com Threads ->  https://pastebin.com/4Bmajhk6

Comment: teria como mostrar como corrigir a parte de "não aceitar mais clientes". Estou tentando aprender corrigindo o que eu tentei fazer. às vezes vendo algo pronto, eu nao acho o meu erro!

Comment: vou criar nova pergunta para não poluir aqui, ok?

Comment: criei pergunta separada para não poluir aqui ->  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/289952/revis%c3%a3o-de-c%c3%b3digo-servidor-com-threads-para-lidar-com-m%c3%baltiplos-clientes

Comment: Comecei a responder mas não tenho tempo para mais, estou a ir jantar agora: https://pastebin.com/g6V3rLUV , vou apagar os comentários para não ficar uma bagunça. @EdS

Answer (score 3):

Este programa tem diversos erros de uso de sockets.

1) Em TCP, envia-se e recebe-se bytes, não mensagens completas. Não existe garantia que um send() vá enviar toda a string fornecida, nem que recv() vá receber uma mensagem completa, muito menos o total de bytes especificado, que é apenas um máximo.

2) É preciso observar o valor de retorno de send() para ver quantos bytes foram efetivamente enviados; se não foram todos, é preciso chamar send() novamente para enviar o resto, geralmente se faz isso num loop.

3) O mesmo vale para recv(), mas no caso de mensagens de tamanho variável, você precisa decidir como vai detectar o "fim da mensagem" - se é uma quebra de linha, ou um número X de bytes, ou outro critério. Não existe o equivalente do radioamador dizendo "over" ou "câmbio" :)

4) Tanto em send() quanto em recv() é preciso testar se enviou ou recebeu zero bytes. Isto significa que a conexão foi fechada. No caso de send(), um retorno menor que zero significa erro, que geralmente acontece ao tentar usar uma conexão já fechada. (No recv() do server você já está fazendo esta checagem.)

5) Isto não é um erro, é uma técnica: para um servidor atender diversos clientes, é preciso lançar mão ou de threads (uma thread tomando conta de cada socket de conexão) ou de programação assíncrona (usando select()).

Cliente melhorado (não está perfeito, mas atenderá múltiplos clientes ao mesmo tempo, que é o que você deseja):

```
from socket import *
import time

serverHost = 'localhost'
serverPort = 50007

# Adotei o caractere \n como fim de mensagem
mensagem = [b'Ola mundo da internet!\n', b'bla\n', b'ble\n']

sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sockobj.connect((serverHost, serverPort))

for linha in mensagem:
    time.sleep(1)

    while linha:
        enviado = sockobj.send(linha)
        if enviado == 0:
            print("Servidor fechou")
            break
        # corta parte da linha ja enviada
        linha = linha[enviado:]

    data = b''
    # Adotei o caractere \n como fim de mensagem
    while b'\n' not in data: 
         newdata = sockobj.recv(1024)
         if not newdata:
             print('Servidor fechou conexao')
             break
         data += newdata
    print('Cliente recebeu:', data)

sockobj.close()
```

Servidor melhorado:

```
from socket import *
import time
import threading

def cuida_cliente(conexao, endereco):
    print('Server conectado a', endereco)
    aberto = True

    while aberto:
        data = b''

        while b'\n' not in data:
            newdata = conexao.recv(1024)
            if not newdata:
                print("Cliente fechou")
                data = b''
                aberto = False
                break
            data += newdata

        if not data:
            break

        msg = b'Eco=>' + data + b'\n'
        while msg:
            enviado = conexao.send(msg)
            if enviado <= 0:
                print("Cliente fechou")
                aberto = False
                break
            msg = msg[enviado:]

    conexao.close()
    return

meuHost = ''
minhaPort = 50007
sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sockobj.bind((meuHost, minhaPort))
sockobj.listen(5)
while True:
    conexao, endereco = sockobj.accept()
    t = threading.Thread(target=cuida_cliente, args=(conexao, endereco))
    t.start()
```

Por completeza, vou incluir uma segunda versão do servidor, baseada em select(), que não precisa de threads e funciona de forma completamente assíncrona. Note que ela é bem mais complexa, mas é considerada muito melhor.

```
from socket import *
import time
import select

# Estrutura que representa um cliente: [socket, buffer recv, buffer send]
clientes = []

# Retorna índice de "clientes" cujo socket seja igual ao passado
def acha_cliente(socket):
    for i, cliente in enumerate(clientes):
        if socket is cliente[0]:
            return i
    return -1

# Cria um cliente novo
def abre_cliente(conexao, endereco):
    print('Server conectado a', endereco)
    clientes.append([conexao, b'', b''])

# Fecha e exclui cliente com erro
def erro_cliente(socket):
    i = acha_cliente(socket)
    if i >= 0:
        clientes[i][0].close()
        del clientes[i]
        return

def recv_cliente(socket):
    i = acha_cliente(socket)
    if i < 0:
        socket.close()
        return

    newdata = socket.recv(1024)
    if not newdata:
        print("Cliente fechou")
        clientes[i][0].close()
        del clientes[i]
        return

    clientes[i][1] += newdata

    if b'\n' in clientes[i][1]:
        # Recebeu msg completa do cliente
        # Coloca mensagem para envio no buffer de transmissão
        clientes[i][2] = b'Eco=>' + clientes[i][1] + b'\n'
        # Limpa buffer de recepcão
        clientes[i][1] = b''

def send_cliente(socket):
    i = acha_cliente(socket)
    if i < 0:
        socket.close()
        return

    # Tenta enviar todo o buffer de transmissão
    enviado = socket.send(clientes[i][2])
    if enviado <= 0:
        print("Cliente fechou")
        clientes[i][0].close()
        del clientes[i]
        return

    # Remove parte já enviada do buffer
    clientes[i][2] = clientes[i][2][enviado:]

meuHost = ''
minhaPort = 50007
sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sockobj.bind((meuHost, minhaPort))
sockobj.listen(5)

while True:
    ler = [sockobj]
    gravar = []
    erro = [sockobj]

    for cliente in clientes:
        # Todo cliente pode enviar dados quando quiser
        ler.append(cliente[0])
        erro.append(cliente[0])
        if cliente[2]:
            # Dados pendentes para envio ao cliente
            gravar.append(cliente[0])

    ler, gravar, erro = select.select(ler, gravar, erro, 10)

    if not ler and not gravar and not erro: 
        print("Timeout")
        continue

    # Despacha erros
    for socket in erro:
        erro_cliente(socket)

    # Despacha leituras
    for socket in ler:
        if socket is sockobj:
            # Socket principal do servidor
            conexao, endereco = sockobj.accept()
            abre_cliente(conexao, endereco)
        else:
            recv_cliente(socket)

    # Despacha gravações
    for socket in gravar:
        send_cliente(socket)
```

Comment: se puder, agradeço! Estou querendo aprender este tópico!

Comment: se pussível, como fazer: "de threads (uma thread tomando conta de cada socket de conexão)"

Comment: Feito conforme pedido.