# Revisão de código: Servidor com threads para lidar com múltiplos clientes

Tags: python, python-3.x, thread

O servidor com Threading:

```
import socket

from threading import Thread



def Servidor():

    servidor = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    ip = "0.0.0.0"
    porta = 8884

    servidor.bind((ip, porta))

    servidor.listen(5)



    while True:
        socket_client, adddress = servidor.accept()

        dados = socket_client.recv(2048)

        print("Cliente: ", dados.decode("utf8"))
        msg = input("Servidor: ")
        enviados = socket_client.send(msg.encode("utf8"))

    servidor.close()



MeuServidor = Thread(target=Servidor,args=[])

MeuServidor.start()
```

o cliente:

```
import socket

ip ="localhost"
porta = 8884

cliente = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

cliente.connect((ip,porta))


while True:

    msg = input("Cliente: ")
    cliente.send(msg.encode("utf8"))
   # print("Cliente: ", msg)
    recebido = cliente.recv(1024)
    print("Servidor: ", recebido.decode("utf8"))

cliente.close()
```

O que está acontecendo: O servidor só aceita um único cliente!

Answer (score 4):

A lógica do servidor deve ser assim:

```
Enquanto verdadeiro:
    Accept (operação bloqueante)
    Criar uma nova Thread e passar para ela o socket_client. Ela deverá ficar em loop tratando a chegada de mensagens até receber ordem de fechar
Fim enquanto
```

Comment: O que está errado no meu código? algo está faltando?

Comment: Seu código não está criando uma Thread para cada socket_client criado a cada accept.

Comment: Teria como corrigir? Estou tentando consertar faz um tempão!

Comment: Agora você me pegou! Não manjo muito de Python hahahah... alguém deve corrigir senão depois eu tento uma resposta

Comment: Já ouvi falar que o módulo threading não é bom. EU deveria usar outro módulo!

Comment: Agradeço! Estou aprendendo ainda. Alguém corrigir me ajuda no aprendizado!